# Javascript output won't accept any CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using simplecart.js which generates data for me to add to a cart, and then passes it to PayPal for me.

I have successfully added the 'add to basket' and 'checkout' features but am finding styling the JS-generated code impossible as no styles applied to it will work.

This is the code site has given to me, which generates a number of items such as name, quantity etc from stored data. It outputs all information correctly but any styles applied to the class names do nothing.

This is the code that generates the data:

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
```

This is the result from the web browser:

```
<div class="simpleCart_items"><div>
<div class="headerRow">
<div class="item-name">Name</div>
<div class="item-price">Price</div>
<div class="item-quantity">Qty</div>

<div class="item-remove"></div>
</div>
<div class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-3">
<div class="item-name">The &nbsp;Jenny&nbsp;Snood&nbsp;£11</div>
<div class="item-price">£11.00</div>
<div class="item-quantity">1</div>
<div class="item-remove">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The browser is receiving all the data correctly, but applying any styles to the class names does nothing. For example, I have:

```
.headerRow{
background-colour:#0F0;
}
```

The result should be that the background of `headerRow` be lime, but nothing happens. It is not calling the style correctly.

I have tried everything but none of the classes will fetch the styles applied to them.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks, obviously not very nice unstyled, but I can't apply any styles at all to it.

[image: Cart unstyled]

[Here is a link to the live site](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)

A further examples:

I've added the code given which generates the totals:

```
<div class="simpleCart_total"></div>
```

I have tried giving it it's own new class and also styling the original, with !important - none of this works.

```
<div class="totals simpleCart_total"></div>
.simpleCart_total{
  background-color:#0F0 !important;
}
.totals{
  background-color:#0F0 !important;
}
```

None of the above seems to have any impact whatsoever.

Comment: I can't even add items to the cart...

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte - browser and system? Adding items to the cart on the live site will only make the price go up, I haven't added anything fancy yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the styles are being applied dynamically by the js after your CSS (ie during the initialization of the plugin). You're only hope is to style it after this initialization with your own js, I think.

You can check this in Firebug... If you look at the elements there, you should see a bunch of inline styles being applied to them. These will trump your CSS in the header (and even the inline CSS you provide beforehand).

**Edit**: I saw some junky characters just before the directives in question (as well as those pointed out in another answer). I would try removing all the white space after the preceding directive and before the broken ones. It does not appear that the js is dynamically changing anything.

Comment: I managed to style the checkout button which is why I'm so confused. Checkout button has the orange styling and works absolutely fine. I'm so annoyed because he simpelcart documentation says it can be 'easily' styled so I assume simple styling would work.... but it seems completely unreliable. Checkout button works but nothing else?!

Comment: Does background-colour vs background-color make a difference?

Comment: Also, use fb as I said to see where the styles are coming from. Your styles will be listed there (crossed out because other styles are overriding them)--this should at least give you a hint at where things went wrong. If it says it's inline, you'll have to use js to fix this as it's probably being dynamically generated by the plugin

Comment: I've been using Chrome to do the same thing but it doesn't show any style full stop, they're neither crossed out, overwritten or whatever. They simply aren't being associated with the class names in the CSS

Comment: there seems to be some kind of strange character in your css just above the .simpleCart_total directive. Looks like this from here: â€‹  It's also in front of .infoText

Comment: please go [here](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/css/style.css) and tell me if you can see it too. If you have some kind of junky character in there just before your directive, it would definitely cancel it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is some other css or inline javascript affecting the custom style your are attempting to use.

To mitigate this issue do one of the following:

- Add !important after each css statement like so:

  .headerRow{background-color:#0F0 !important;}
- Reorder the css files so your custom css file is at the bottom

Comment: Can you work out why the checkout button and empty button are not affected? I don't udnerstand why one is fine being styled while the others refuse to budge...

Comment: the one that isn't changing is more than likely being change dynamically with javascript. So if you want to bypass the javascript add !important and you will be fine

Comment: adding !important does nothing.